# HaxeFlixel icon is whiteout

Tags: haxe

When I build for Android or Windows, the icon is always whiteout. I've tried SVG, PNG and none of those works.

```
    <icon path="assets/images/default-icon.svg" />
```

or

```
    <icon path="assets/images/default-icon.png" />
```